# Getting the highest values from the database

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am using the following query to grab delivery types from an SQL database, the query gets all delivery types associated with the list of products in the shopping cart. The query could return a minimum of two delivery types for one product or many more for multiple products within the cart. However i just need the two most expensive delivery cost to be displayed.

E.G.
Product 1 has Std Delivery £9.99 AND 2 Man delivery £29.99
Product 2 has Std Delivery £18.95 AND 2 Man Delivery £39.99

I need to display to the screen the delivery types for product 2. Can i use the max function or will that only return the highest delivery price?

Query being used:

```
<cfquery name="getDeliveryType" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT 
  uid_pdelopt,
  txt_pdelopt_type,
  mon_pdelopt_cost,
  uid_pdelopt_prodid,
  txt_pdelopt_detail,
  bit_pdelopt_active,
  bit_pdelopt_selected,
  uid_pdelopt_webid,
  uid_pdelopt_typeid,
  mon_pdelopt_actcost
    FROM dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt
    WHERE bit_pdelopt_active=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes">
   AND uid_pdelopt_prodid IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.uid_pdelopt_prodid#" list="yes">)
</cfquery>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by cost DESC and limit the results to 2

```
<cfquery name="getDeliveryType" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT TOP 2
  uid_pdelopt,
  txt_pdelopt_type,
  mon_pdelopt_cost,
  uid_pdelopt_prodid,
  txt_pdelopt_detail,
  bit_pdelopt_active,
  bit_pdelopt_selected,
  uid_pdelopt_webid,
  uid_pdelopt_typeid,
  mon_pdelopt_actcost
    FROM dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt
    WHERE bit_pdelopt_active=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes">
   AND uid_pdelopt_prodid IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.uid_pdelopt_prodid#" list="yes">)

    ORDER BY mon_pdelopt_cost DESC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Once again my over thinking was getting in the way!! However is LIMIT allowed in SQL as i get a Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT' error returned. Thanks for your quick response!!

Comment: I suppose the alternative is TOP, but this gets the wrong results!

Comment: If you use SQL Server, you need to change that. LIMIT doesn't work in SQL Server. Try `SELECT TOP 2 uid_pdelopt,...`  instead

Comment: Try FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY (at least that's the standard syntax).

Comment: I was being a numpty, I was ordering by the wrong field. Works a treat now with TOP 2, can you edit the post to reflect this and i will select the answer as correct! Thank you.

Comment: If you need just the two highest costs in all rows, then the query is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Again, the above all works but I think I may have asked the wrong question fro the desired results. This will indeed return the two records with the highest cost, but I need the highest cost of the std delivery and the highest cost of the two man delivery i.e 

Std Delivery Highest Cost and Two Man delivery highest cost. Shall i ask another question or do you have any pointers?

Comment: I see. It is a bit more tricky, but I will try and post an updated query

Comment: I have tried the following query which looks like it works, but I need to pull other fields from the table as well.
`<cfquery name="getDeliveryType" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT
  txt_pdelopt_type, MAX(mon_pdelopt_actcost) AS myCost
  FROM dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt
  WHERE bit_pdelopt_active=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes">
   AND uid_pdelopt_prodid IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="5,49" list="yes">)
   GROUP BY txt_pdelopt_type
  
   </cfquery>`

Comment: To add new fields to the select, you must add them in the GROUP BY clause, but after txt_pdelopt_type, so they are still grouped first of all by delivery type. If multiple rows has the same txt_pdelopt_type and you group by other fields, it will display rows for each different combination. Let me know if that worked

Comment: If i use other fields it returns more records than needed and includes the cheaper versions. Would you do it like i am trying?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this to see if it works:

```
SELECT TOP 2
 txt_pdelopt_type, MAX(mon_pdelopt_actcost) AS myCost, OTHER_FIELD

FROM dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt 

WHERE bit_pdelopt_active=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes"> AND uid_pdelopt_prodid IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="5,49" list="yes">) 

GROUP BY uid_pdelopt_prodid, txt_pdelopt_type, OTHER_FIELD

ORDER BY myCost DESC
```

Change OTHER_FIELD with eventual other fields you might need.

Comment: not sure the `</cfquery>` bit should be there, do i take it out and leave the parenthesis in place. thanks for your help on this!!!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Move `</cfquery>` in the end of the query where it belongs

Comment: Hi this now produces 72 results
http://cfukstaging.jasoncongerton.co.uk/test.cfm i set up a testing page for results

Comment: Yes, I changed a bit they query, could you try the new one? I added the product id in the group by. We should have done that from the begining.

Comment: weird! this now gets the cheaper of the delivery types?? also adding more selects produces more results

Comment: It computes the MAX delivery type for each product id, for each delivery type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7563/discussion-between-mazzucci-and-jason-congerton)